# gst-rtsp-server multicast not working - GStreamer

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

I'm trying to establish multicast RSTP streaming using [this server](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server) provided by GStreamer. I've compiled version 1.16.2.

I launch example multicast/multicast2 server from examples and I'm trying to connect to this server from another virtual machine using pipeline: `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc protocols=udp-mcast location=rtsp://192.168.10.110:8554/test latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! autovideosink` and I get:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayX11\)\ gldisplayx11-0";
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://192.168.10.110:8554/test
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 1
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Could not read from resource.
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(5448): gst_rtspsrc_reconnect (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
Could not receive any UDP packets for 5,0000 seconds, maybe your firewall is blocking it. No other protocols to try.
Execution ended after 0:00:05.110990765
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I've set multicast routing at those machines with `ip route add 224.0.0.0/4 dev enp0s3`

Unicast streaming works just fine. What am I doing wrong? Below packets captured with wireshark:

[image: wireshark captured packets]

Comment: I've found related articles:
https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-devel/2017-January/062277.html

https://gstreamer-devel.narkive.com/T4NHf6TU/rtsp-multicast-scenario-setup

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of it? I am having the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

you are not getting a source filter in the request (SSM)
i would expect the rtsp/SDP handshake to have a source filter line in. The pink "for any sources" shouts that your SSM is not filled in here correctly and your end device is not SSM compliant